# Align content in a fixed footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code a simple download page, but I can't get what I want to.

An image is worth a thousand words, so I sketched what I would like to get:
[image]

For now, I figured out how to:

- keep the box fixed to the bottom, while
- keeping the page scrollable

But I can't understand how to make the title and the button aligned in different sides, and the content of the "footer" aligned vertically...

Here's the actual "code"...

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: #fff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #222;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
  font-family: "Gotham SSm A";
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
}

a {
  transition: 0.2s all;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: "Gotham SSm A";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 0;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background: #F9BF3B;
}

.download {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1%;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.5);
}

.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="download">
  <div class="left">
    <p>left-aligned text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <a href="#" class="button">button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this could help you understand the various approaches for centering/aligning stuff with CSS: [howtocenterincss](http://howtocenterincss.com/)

Comment: @Aziz that's fabulous, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Weave made with [Preprocessors](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/preprocessors/)**: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#6a3f265ea39a9e4c296718eb64e08ecf
**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#b3ebebb74666da608e8d8a19f2a1690d

Always try to keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Considering your new to this I'm going to point a few things out before I answer your question. (but first checkout [Common CSS questions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Common_CSS_Questions))

*There are a few errors in your code, remember that...*
The universal selector `*` is known to be slow (only use it when absolutely necessary, because of this it's best to avoid using it as much as possible). **NOTE:** By default the html and body tags have a `width 100%`.

You should always utilize a good CSS reset library into your projects ([Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is my personal favorite). This saves you most of the headache of styling your elements to work on other browsers.
As for CSS3 you would need something like [Prefix-free](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) or [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to...

> Break free from CSS prefix hell!

With that said.

The first thing I did was focus on centering your footer content.

In this case using `margin`, `translate`, `position relative` & `top` would be bad practice to center your text vertically. (The only relevant reason to use it would be if the font || font-size was different on the button than the default text, but in this case it's not so DON'T USE IT! (Remember [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

To align your text vertically you can use <kbd>[`display table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)</kbd>, <kbd>[`display table-cell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/empty-cells)</kbd> and <kbd>[`vertical-align middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)</kbd>

In this case it'd be best to use [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) instead of [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).

With that said by using [`display table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) and [positioning the footer at the bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). <kbd>[see code](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#b3ebebb74666da608e8d8a19f2a1690d)</kbd> I was able to alleviate unnecessary uses of [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear), [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) and [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Content Padding */
.content {
  padding: 1em;
}

/* Position and Style Footer */
.download {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.056em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
/* Footer Typography */
.download, .button {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Margin Button to Center */
.button {
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #F9BF3B;
}

/* Vertically Align Content */
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.cell {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Variable Classes */
.left {
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
}

/* Styles Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: #fff;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #222;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/4.1.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/prefixfree.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa praesentium velit quas esse itaque voluptate eos alias deserunt veniam, molestias exercitationem, maiores sed et vitae, iusto autem cum eaque? Maxime.</p>
  <p>Rerum, tempore, debitis! Ducimus perferendis qui doloribus ab, deleniti error cumque eaque consequatur soluta. Quidem incidunt, commodi qui soluta sed aut suscipit, nisi dolore. Tempora ipsa ut quod ipsum autem!</p>
  <p>Illo nisi eos quam neque adipisci a id autem sed distinctio, recusandae iure rem maiores, facere fugiat, harum sit reprehenderit dignissimos quaerat ut. Necessitatibus iure, suscipit blanditiis ipsum consectetur! Illum!</p>
  <p>Magnam autem dicta architecto necessitatibus accusamus expedita, at, accusantium nobis dolorem repellat vero earum beatae sunt iusto aut veritatis numquam deserunt blanditiis officia nihil! Ad, amet consectetur maiores quia earum?</p>
  <p>Nisi libero voluptatibus modi facere laboriosam ex provident. Quae dolorem tempore rem quia voluptate nisi consequuntur rerum earum fugiat neque, aperiam, iste culpa deserunt eligendi eos aspernatur ex harum ea.</p>
  <p>Adipisci, itaque ullam! Quis culpa tempora sunt dignissimos eaque porro laudantium excepturi, fugit quasi ex dolor repellendus neque magnam repellat fuga aliquid odio, veniam dicta cumque, laborum placeat rem commodi.</p>
  <p>Ad sunt optio nostrum, distinctio repellendus dignissimos, cum aut quos sed excepturi, nulla qui molestias? Ad quia, eligendi! Quam facilis consequatur laboriosam, adipisci et. Debitis ea facere ullam iure repellendus?</p>
  <p>Laborum, distinctio necessitatibus. Odit voluptatem fugit sint voluptates rem distinctio animi nihil beatae, molestiae explicabo tempora vero quam! Quidem autem itaque eos ratione voluptatum veritatis eveniet vitae aperiam aut voluptates?</p>
  <p>Soluta eos tempore, eum ducimus pariatur repellendus quaerat praesentium laudantium? Molestias laborum odio ratione temporibus rem id, excepturi magnam delectus facilis quibusdam quaerat exercitationem veniam vero architecto provident dolore sed.</p>
  <p>Quia, debitis odit obcaecati mollitia sunt enim natus ipsum, beatae corporis laborum id provident velit laudantium eveniet, fugiat. Velit minus ipsum nihil nemo, eos vero, soluta quos ab accusamus obcaecati.</p>
  <p>Nam quis, esse iure aliquid? Rem temporibus nemo aspernatur cupiditate accusamus, explicabo totam laboriosam odit magni quaerat maxime culpa vitae! Repellat velit quos eaque temporibus, tempore neque odio ex deserunt?</p>
  <p>Eveniet, unde quas debitis rem laboriosam cumque praesentium animi veniam temporibus ullam ipsam modi minima iusto repellat, tenetur reiciendis dolorum, officia dolor possimus. Esse quidem vitae perspiciatis velit a fuga.</p>
</div>

<div class="table">
  <div class="download">
    <div class="cell left">
      <p>left-aligned text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="cell right">
      <a class="button" href="javascript:void(0)">button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was swap out `display:inline` to this:

```
.left {
float:left;
margin-top:13px; 
}

.right {
float:right;
}
```

Added `margin-top:13px;` to align vertically

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/3vcb0fwo/1/) a bunch of Hi's (fiddle)

Comment: Thanks, the float thing helped me a lot, anyway, I found an awesome way to vertically align everything:

position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);

It's too awesome.

Comment: Damn, I really wanted to be the right answer :P I'm glad you solved it! Have a nice day :)